# D3JS: Efficient display of binary timeseries

Tags: javascript, d3.js, time-series

I need to display a time series of binary vectors in a d3js graph. Every time point is associated with a binary vector of length 100, i.e. (x:75, y:[1001101...]).

So far, I'm representing the value of each 1 and 0 as circle that is either red or blue. However, the data is at a resolution of 1Hz and I seek to show 15 min worth of data at a time. This results in having to render 90.000 circles (60*15*100).

Updating the graph is painfully slow because 90.000 circles need to be updated when new data is coming in. Past values don't change but new data is coming in.

What is a good representation of the data? I thought about pre-rendering every binary vector as a BMP and then updating 900 BMPs instead of 90.000 circles but I am not sure if that is an elegant solution to the problem.